# Adding a "Report the post" button/form?

Tags: forms, spam

I have a user-generated-content website with WP.

I would like to allow the readers to notify me of posts that should be taken down.

I need to:

1. add a button to the end of each posts, that when clicked, will send the reader to another form, while taking with it the url from which it came
2. I need a form that will hold several dropdown options to choose from, and a "send this report" ability (coupled with some CAPTCHA)

I would appreciate any idea/ plugin on how to do this.

([this older question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42456/how-to-make-simply-report-button-on-posts) didn't solve the problem for me, at my current level of understanding)

Answer (score -1):

To use the plugin in the question you linked to:

1. Copy the code into notepad or an equivalent program
2. Save the file using the extension `.php` (make sure your operating system has file endings turned on so it doesn't save as `filename.php.txt`
3. Put the file into a compressed (or zipped) folder. How you do this depends on your operating system.
4. Upload the zipped folder to your wordpress blog. (Plugins->add new->upload)
5. Activate the plugin.